# Not sure how to reattach two bathroom objects

Tags: bathroom, pipe, sink, trim

About a year ago we had a contractor switch out a cabinet for a pedestal style sink. I didn't notice until recently that behind the sink there was a loose ring object on the outflow pipe and the molding (did I get that right?) is loose

The top red circle has a loose ring around it, what is that called? If I push it against the wall it doesn't fit in the hole. It does not look like it was glued on initially. How should I fix it so it covers the hole?

The other red circle at the bottom. Do I need to hammer a nail into that molding to get it to stay against the wall and spackle/paint over the nail?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is that called?

The *true* name is escutcheon, the common name is pipe flange or trim flange. Those escutcheons are typically designed to gently grip the pipe with small bendy metal tabs that are part of the escutcheon. Other (better quality) ones have a set-screw that holds them to the pipe. The bendy tabs on yours are probably now ineffective and your only options are to either remove and replace or try to get it to stick to the wall with some strategically placed globs of caulk and tape to hold it till cured.

> Do I need to hammer a nail into that molding to get it to stay against the wall and spackle/paint over the nail?

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.